# typescript How to constrain the key of a generic type to be string only

Tags: typescript

I want a generic type `OnlyStringKey<T>` like below.

```
   //This line has no compile errors
    let x: OnlyStringKey<{whatEverJustString1: 1, whatEverJustString2: '' }>;
    
    //This line has error. Because key 2 is a number but a string
    let x: OnlyStringKey<{whatEverJustString1: 1, 2: '' }>;
    
    //This line has error too. Because key symbol.search is symbole but a string
    let x: OnlyStringKey<{whatEverJustString1: 1, [Symbol.search]: '' }>;
```

I have tried several method. And none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following constraint to `OnlyStringKey`:

```
type OnlyStringKey<
  T extends Record<string, any> & Record<number | symbol, never> 
> = T
```

This will make sure that all `number` and `symbol` keys can only have the type `never`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQhQBcE8AcFNgPIDsA2kDK4BOBLJBzAaVkgB5QQAVYWAD3FiQBMBnYAJVgGMB7LJ0i2x58AGmABDJJAB8wCiGAAyDtz4CkAVwC2AI1hZgAH2AtIeninFJYANwNzQcgLzBKoDwHpPlABY42FDx4Xwk2JB5gXm1oHBR4Ayw+FlB48GBaAEYALkRUDGECYjIAbwB3UPAAUXssAClNIUxcAhzgTPEKiWrahqbC-AAmXIByEeAAXxkAbi8ff0Dg4FC2RL4AOmAAIW4JRvgAaxJgQeAAyWAtPQNgXU10iVMB1Nh02mG8tGaRYtJyypqBj64G+rVyHROo3GU1moG8fnOQRsyzCNCwSUM4B4PE2Oy4exYh2OZgsKHWhIkWC4vjObBJuks8DuDyeLXwLzeAGZcsgvgNfv9uoD6o0QQM2hCANrocwMskUqm+AC6UMmMyAA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think type can be constrained and be generic at the same time, but you may want something like `OnlyStringKey: Record<string, any> or OnlyStringKey:{ [key: string]: any }`